# How to dynamically change the styles in the class to be used in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, button, angular6

As of the moment, I could already change design of the buttons by using ng-container. A snippet of that code is below.

```
  <ng-container *ngIf="isDisabled;">
        <button class="bot-btn-disabled"
                (click)="confirm()"
                [disabled]=this.isDisabled >
          Confirm
        </button>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container *ngIf="!isDisabled;">
    <button class="bot-btn"
            (click)="confirm()"
            [disabled]=this.isDisabled >
      Confirm
    </button>
  </ng-container>
```

However, this seems to long for , as I just need to change the class="bot-btn"  of my button that if isDisabled = false, it will change to that style which is bot-btn and vice versa. Is there any way of doing this the shorter way?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `class` on your button based on the condition like this:

```
[ngClass]="this.isDisabled ? 'bot-btn-disabled' : 'bot-btn'"
```

Comment: thx, that worked great. Haven't used that ngClass directive yet. Now I know. :D

Answer (score 1):

`ngClass` directive can accept an object where keys are CSS classes that get added when the expression given in the value evaluates to a truthy value, otherwise they are removed .

```
  <button 
        [ngClass]="{'bot-btn-disabled': this.isDisabled ,'bot-btn' : !this.isDisabled " } 
        (click)="confirm()"
        [disabled]=this.isDisabled >
              Confirm
   </button>
```

others values ngClass accept are `string` or `array` check the demo in the  [documentation page](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass#description)